# Trend analysis (increasing, decreasing and no trend) in a tabular format

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` `df` that consists of 4 sites. Each site has four parameters (A, B, C and D) and I have the value for each parameter from 2011 to 2014

```
siteID <- c(rep("site1", 16), rep("site2", 16), rep("site3", 16),rep("site4", 16))
YEAR <-   rep(c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"), 16)
parameter <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4))
value <- c(seq(1, 4, by=1), seq(10, 40, by=10), seq(12, 18, by=2), seq(5, 20, by=5),
           seq(3, 12, by=3), sample(13:18, 4), sample(15:22, 4), sample(10:18, 4),
           seq(7, 1, by=-2), sample(15:22, 4), sample(15:19, 4), sample(10:20, 4),
           seq(8, 5, by=-1), seq(50, 20, by=-10), seq(16, 10, by=-2), seq(20, 5, by=-5))
df <- data.frame(siteID, YEAR, parameter, value)


head(df, 20)
#    siteID YEAR parameter value
#1   site1 2011         A     1
#2   site1 2012         A     2
#3   site1 2013         A     3
#4   site1 2014         A     4
#5   site1 2011         B    10
#6   site1 2012         B    20
#7   site1 2013         B    30
#8   site1 2014         B    40
#9   site1 2011         C    12
#10  site1 2012         C    14
#11  site1 2013         C    16
#12  site1 2014         C    18
#13  site1 2011         D     5
#14  site1 2012         D    10
#15  site1 2013         D    15
#16  site1 2014         D    20
#17  site2 2011         A     3
#18  site2 2012         A     6
#19  site2 2013         A     9
#20  site2 2014         A    12
```

I can get an idea about the trend in data through the plot below

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = YEAR, y= value, col= parameter))+
      geom_line(aes(group=parameter))+
      facet_wrap(~siteID)
```

[image]

However, if I have many sites (e.g. 70 sites), it will be more time taking to analyse the trend visually for all parameters. Is there anyway I could get the trend in data in a table like the one below

```
siteID   parameter   trend
site1    A           increasing    
site1    B           decreasing
site1    C           no trend
site1    D           increasing
.
site4    A           decreasing
site4    B           decreasing 
site4    C           increasing
site4    D           decreasing
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Comment: Read about `lm()`.

Comment: @zx8754

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic solution is to transform your data frame into wide format and then add a column in which you establish the conditions for increasing, decreasing or no trend. In the example no trend if the variation is +-2.

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- dcast(df, siteID + parameter ~ YEAR, value.var="value")
df2$trend <- ifelse(df2$`2014`-df2$`2011`>2, "increasing", 
                ifelse(df2$`2014`-df2$`2011`< -2, "decreasing", "no trend"))
df2
```

Output:

```
   siteID parameter 2011 2012 2013 2014      trend
1   site1         A    1    2    3    4 increasing
2   site1         B   10   20   30   40 increasing
3   site1         C   12   14   16   18 increasing
4   site1         D    5   10   15   20 increasing
5   site2         A    3    6    9   12 increasing
6   site2         B   16   17   14   15   no trend
7   site2         C   16   20   18   19 increasing
8   site2         D   16   13   11   12 decreasing
9   site3         A    7    5    3    1 decreasing
10  site3         B   20   22   17   16 decreasing
11  site3         C   17   19   15   18   no trend
12  site3         D   19   12   17   20   no trend
13  site4         A    8    7    6    5 decreasing
14  site4         B   50   40   30   20 decreasing
15  site4         C   16   14   12   10 decreasing
16  site4         D   20   15   10    5 decreasing
```